# input "datetime-local" > js code that makes the seconds run/move accurately for time to update

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to find out how to have the seconds run/move accurately for the time to change. is there a way I can do that with the js script that I have provided below?

thank you all.

```js
functionName(); //First execution
 setInterval(functionName, 1000); //Ask the browser to execute functionName as soon as possible after 1 second has passed

function functionName(){
   var now = new Date();
   now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
   document.getElementById('dt').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
}
```

```html
<input readonly="readonly" name="dt" id="dt" type="datetime-local" step="1" />
```

Comment: _"Check every second"_ - "Ask the browser to execute `functionName` as soon as possible after 1 second has passed" would be more accurate

Comment: My comment was not meant as an edit suggestion^^ It was meant as a hint and a clarification on how that `setInterval()` call actually works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `getSeconds` and `setSeconds` works:

I also changed the string slice to `.slice(0,19)` to show the updated seconds.

```js
functionName(); //First execution
 setInterval(functionName, 1000); //Ask the browser to execute functionName as soon as possible after 1 second has passed

function functionName(){
   var now = new Date();
   now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
   document.getElementById('dt').value = now.toISOString().slice(0,19);
}
```

```html
<input readonly="readonly" name="dt" id="dt" type="datetime-local" step="1" />
```